# Bep20 - I sent the token to the Token Address

Tags: tokens, contract-design, addresses, contract-debugging, recovery

I accidentally sent the token to the contract itself. This mistake is worth more than $300,000 as of now. I was wondering if ANYONE could look over the code and help me resolve this issue. Is there anything in the contract code that would allow me to recover the lost tokens?

Here is the token contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x9abdba20edfba06b782126b4d8d72a5853918fd0#code

Here is the transaction:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xf39a3806a2cb23d33b56828d43cfc8221266dd45b3a9dffefbe2c84c66b0a463

I will reward whoever helps me with a lot of money.

Comment: If you sent a token to a contract address there’s no way to get them back even if the contract’s owner wanted. Unless said contract that received the tokens had implemented a function that allows it to transfer received tokens, they are lost and stuck. ( I will see if the contract has such a function, but I doubt it)